# Do not say that you are 'sorry for' something

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adjectives

Page 390 of Collins English Usage reads

> When you are apologizing to someone for something that has happened,
> you can say that you are sorry **about** it.
>
> *She was very sorry about all
> the trouble she'd caused.*
>
> Note that you do not say that you are 'sorry for' something.

Isn't it contradictory? A common counterexample: *We are sorry for any inconvenience caused*

Comment: _Sorry for noun (phrase)  vs sorry for + ing verb?_

Comment: Where is the contradiction? Do you mean "apologizing to someone **for** something" but not "sorry **for** it"?

Comment: This question is not really a duplicate, because what can be found on the linked page is precisely what makes the quotation from Collins English Usage puzzling. This question is seeking an explanation of that quotation.

Comment: I don't know why Collins tell you not to use 'sorry for', when it certainly is often used in that context. However, note that 'be sorry for' can also mean 'feel pity or sympathy for'.

Comment: Many usage guides are "prescriptivist", and contradict what has become common usage. It's similar to telling you not to split an infinitive or end a sentence with a preposition.